# What materials do I need to fix these walls? (not even sure if it's actually drywall)

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, drywall-mud

The holes are right around the frame to a window. Not really sure how to fix it. It ended up like this after I removed anchors from the wall that the previous tenant left behind. Some of them were stuck in pretty deep.

Thanks in advance for any help!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is just drywall with joint compound.

To start you should secure the corner bead (the metal strip), just a screw in the hole nearest the open corner will suffice.

If there is any more loose joint compound or paint scrape it off now.

Then you can put spread new joint compound over the holes and the corner bead. When its dry, sand. You will probably need two coats to get it smooth.

This is a very easy repair and rather cheap. You can buy one of the small buckets of joint compound such as [this one](https://www.lowes.com/pd/SHEETROCK-Brand-1-75-Pint-S-Premixed-All-purpose-Drywall-Joint-Compound/3014170). At the cheapest a plastic putty knife ([lowes link](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Warner-6-in-Putty-Knife/3959157)) (I'd get a proper metal one. You will use it again, and it is also good for scraping).

Last thing is just to prime and paint. (the painting will be the most expensive part).

Comment: Don't forget the sandpaper!

Comment: I would use tape or mesh to give it some strength, if only mud when the next screw goes in it will break up, the tape or mesh really strengthens the patch. As bad as that is I might cut the sections out and fit a new piece. But a patch would work.

Comment: The OP is probably in the US ("drywall" rather than "plasterboard"), but in the UK I would use Polyfilla or similar filler to repair.  (It is quite likely "filler" is the UK term for what is called "jointing compound" in the US.)